# Save my credentials in Office 365

Tags: office-365, authentication

We are currently experiencing a problem when the check box "Save my credentials" is ticked, it doesn't actually save the credentials when logging into SharePoint (Office 365). I'm hoping someone else has experienced this issue and might have a solution.

Comment: Which browser ?

Comment: Internet Explorer

Comment: Got https://*.sharepoint.com saved to your Trusted Sites?

Comment: Yes - We've added a all the recommend including https://*.sharepoint.com https://*.office365.com, https://*.microsoftonline.com, https://*.outlook.com